# what is the relation between a minimum phase system and a FIR system?

Tags: linear-phase, finite-impulse-response

I want to see whats the relation between being an FIR system and a minimum phase system and when an FIR system can be minimum phase too with respect to have linear phase

Comment: What do you mean by "can be minimum phase too with respect to have linear phase"? It's either minimum-phase or linear phase, but not both (except for the trivial case mentioned in hotpaw2's answer).

Answer (score 1):

The only FIR system that is both minimum phase and linear phase is where the output is the same as the input: y[i] = x[i]